# What does ?* mean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to understand what this means

```
 variableName * ?*
```

I understand that `VariableName` is being multiplied with something, but what does `?*` mean? Is this regex and does it mean that I'm appending '`?`' and anything that comes after it?

Comment: Can you show a little bit more context? Please post the entire method, statement, etc.

Comment: this is deliberate. i would like to learn every possible scenario this can be used.

Answer (score 2):

`?c` is not a regex, is the short syntax for `'*'`. That is, `?a` is `'a'`, `?b` is `'b'` etc...
What is going on in your program is probably something like:

```
["ab","cd","ef"] * ?*
#=> "ab*cd*ef"
```